# How to move text from end of string to start

Tags: regex

Here are two lines from some text that I wanted to change

```
Dorset Rd (5) - 2018-12-14 11-01-05
Crampton Chas - Sandarra Blvd - 2018-12-27 12-31-56
```

I’m trying to move the date and time from the end of each line to the start to produce this

```
2018-12-14 11-01-05 - Dorset Rd (5)
2018-12-27 12-31-56 - Crampton Chas - Sandarra Blvd
```

Through reading this forum (thanks to you all), I have come up with the following regex

```
(^.*)\s-\s(.*$)
```

And used this as the replacement

```
$2 - $1
```

This works fine, but I have two questions:

1. I’m wondering why the ‘\s-\s’ found the last occurrence of ‘ - ‘ instead of the first?
2. Could this have been better done by picking up the last 19 characters and somehow moving them to the start?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I’m wondering why the ‘\s-\s’ found the last occurrence of ‘ - ‘ instead of the first?

Because the first `*` is greedy. It matches everything first, then it backtracks until the stuff after it matches the rest of the string. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2301285/what-do-lazy-and-greedy-mean-in-the-context-of-regular-expressions).

> Could this have been better done by picking up the last 19 characters and somehow moving them to the start?

If your date format will always have 19 characters, sure!

```
^(.*) - (.{19})$
```

replace with the same replacement.

Not sure if this is "better" though, without knowing what you mean by "better".

Comment: I've now learnt what 'greedy' means. Thx
I noticed that where I used `(^.*)` you used `^(.*)`. Is there a difference?

Comment: @RedOchre there is no difference. `^` matches a zero width string, so it doesn’t matter if it is in the group or not.